# AWS Resource Share not allowing me to share EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to share all EC2 instances across all users in my AWS organization. Im trying to do this by making a resource share in the RAM console, however I don't see EC2 in this list of resources which is confusing to me. Is this the right way to share EC2 instances across an organization?
[image]

Comment: No, there is no way to share an instance itself. What does sharing mean to you? What is your goal?

Comment: Not a single instance. I would like to share ALL EC2 instances with ALL users. For example, if I create an EC2 instance anyone in my organization can see it and edit it also.

Comment: Absolutely not possible, neither seeing them nor editing them. Not how EC2 works. You cannot share instances.

Comment: Create a role in your account and let all other accounts assume that role and grant the role the relevant ec2 permissions.